# Swift Firebase observing не работает

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, firebase, observer

Не работает observe правильно. 
На фото я все показал, если ошибка в моем коде, подскажите пожалуйста.

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fha7.jpg)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не стоит вставлять код в виде скриншотов.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором observer стоит snapshot вместо snap